# How to find exact roots in python (for cubics)

Tags: python, math

A program I'm writing involves solving many cubic polynomials. Upon using np.roots, it appears to me that for cubics, the roots are 'approximated roots'.

```
In [5]: np.roots([1,3,3,1])
Out[5]: array([-0.99999672+5.68937417e-06j, -0.99999672-5.68937417e-06j,
   -1.00000657+0.00000000e+00j])
```

So, the roots seem to be pretty close to being correct, in terms of the real parts being very close to -1, and the complex parts being very small, or nonexistent.

It is important for me that integer roots come out as integers, and not some real/complex number that 'closely resembles' it (roughly speaking).

Any input is appreciated, thank you in advance.

Comment: You could round the real part and check if it gives you a root.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille I think I'm going to end up doing this. Thanks.

Comment: This effect is due to some initial normalization of the coefficients, so that for instance the largest coefficient is 1, or the root radius is smaller than 1. This introduces rounding errors, so that the resulting polynomial is some `(1+x)^3+mu*q(x)` where q is some quasi-random quadratic polynomial. The roots of that will be close to `-1-(mu*q(-1))**(1/3)`, and with `mu=2e-16` the deviation has magnitude `1e-5`.

Comment: @LutzL So it's transforming a given polynomial into a normalized form (normalized by some standards, such as the two you mentioned)? But this normalized form may be a slight approximation, so when the roots of the 'normalized' polynomial are used to find the roots of the original polynomial (in some sort of reverse transformation), the roots are slightly off? 

Thanks for sharing this piece of information.

Comment: Yes, scaling the coefficients in floating point and applying the inverse scaling formula may introduce small errors. This also happens without scaling for test polynomials like `(x-5/7)^5`, expanded in floating point. The form of the root cluster is a regular triangle or m-gon around the "true" root, where m is the multiplicity. I forgot to add the phase factor in the root formula above.

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/105554/factoring-polynomials-completely

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are willing to use [`sympy`](https://www.sympy.org/):

```
from sympy import var, Eq, solve

x = var('x')
sol = solve(Eq(x**3 + 3*x**2 + 3*x + 1, 0), x)
print(sol)  # output: [-1]
```

`factor` could also be used to verify the solution:

```
from sympy import factor
fact = factor(x**3 + 3*x**2 + 3*x + 1)
print(fact)  # (x + 1)**3
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll give this a shot now. Do both sympy and numpy come with anaconda? Are they disjoint in terms of which modules they contain?

Comment: @Kenchi: Yes, both sympy and numpy come with Anaconda and are installed by default. Both are part of the scipy stack.

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume that the coefficients of your cubic polynomials are integers, since that is true of your example.

I see at least two ways to do what you want. First, you can use `np.roots` as you have been. Then round each solution to the nearest (real) integer and plug that integer into the original polynomial--this can be done with exact precision. If the result of the polynomial is zero, use that integer rather than the returned root. If it would help, you could round to the nearest [Gaussian integer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integer) and try that--that may be useful for your needs

Another way is for you to search for integral roots before using `np.roots`. You can  use the [Rational Root Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem) to search for those integer roots. This involves factoring the constant and leading coefficients. This method will also find rational but non-integral roots, which you may want. If the coefficients are large, finding the factors and/or trying all the possibilities may be time-consuming.

Comment: Thank you! Good suggestions. Rounding and plugging back in is something I was hoping to avoid with a module, but if I use the rational root theorem before using np.roots, the whole process should be relatively clean.